# how to find out list of unused Lambdas in AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

We have lots of Lambda functions in our AWS account which was created by ex-employees.
I have to get a list of Lambdas which were not used in the last six months and delete them.
Also, how can I find out if there are any dependent objects on those Lambdas?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need fully custom solution for that, e.g. checking invocation metrics of all of those functions.

Comment: Besides what Marcin said, what do you mean by dependent objects?

Comment: I would like to know what programs these lambdas are getting called?

Answer (score -1):

How about automating this task through a script and this will save your time in future as well. This is one of the very well written blog along with the solution. Give it a try
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mt/automating-the-discovery-of-unused-aws-lambda-functions/

Comment: This one is tried and tested and one of the easier ways to list unused lambda's
https://github.com/epsagon/list-lambdas